# Method of steepest descent: why can we relate these two contours?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, asymptotics

Let $f,g:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be two functions which are holomorphic in $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$. Consider the integral $$I(\lambda)=\int_{\Gamma}g(z)e^{\lambda f(z)}dz,\quad \lambda \in (0,+\infty)$$

where $\Gamma$ is a contour in $\Omega$. I want to understand the method of steepest descend which allows to approximate $I(\lambda)$ as $\lambda \to +\infty$.

Now, if I understand, the rough idea is to deform the contour into another contour $\Gamma'$ passing through a saddle point of $f(z)$ in the direction of steepest descent of its real part.

To do so we look for a saddle point $f'(z_0)=0$, expand $f(z)$ up to second order around it $$f(z)=f(z_0)+\frac{1}{2}(z-z_0)f''(z_0)+\cdots$$

and we parameterize $z - z_0 = r_1e^{i\theta_1}$. Also letting $\frac{1}{2}f''(z_0)=r_2 e^{i\theta_2}$ we have the changes in the real and imaginary parts of $f$: $$\operatorname{Re}[f(z)-f(z_0)]=r_1^2r_2\cos(2\theta_1+\theta_2),\quad \operatorname{Im}[f(z)-f(z_0)]=r_1^2r_2\sin(2\theta_1+\theta_2).$$

The direction of steepest descent has vanishing change in the imaginary part and negative change in the real part. These two conditions give $2\theta_1+\theta_2$ either $\pi$ or $3\pi$. Therefore the desired contour $\Gamma'$ can be parameterized as $$z(t)=z_0+\frac{t}{\sqrt{r_2}}e^{i\theta_1}$$

Question: why can we deform $\Gamma$ into $\Gamma'$ and not change $I(\lambda)$?

I mean, I *do know* that from Cauchy's theorem *if $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ have the same endpoints* then the integral is the same along both.

But in this whole derivation I see no reason why $\Gamma'$ would share endpoints with $\Gamma$.

Comment: It's a prerequisite that it should be possible to deform $\Gamma$ into $\Gamma'$ s.t. $\Gamma'$ locally goes through a saddle point in the direction of the steepest descent and that $\operatorname {Re} f$ has its maximum (globally on $\Gamma'$) at the saddle point. The choice of a saddle point and of $\Gamma'$ depends on the geometry of the level curves of $\operatorname {Re} f$ (see examples [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3185782)).

Answer (score 1):

The rough idea behind the [method of steepest descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent) is as follows.

1. By [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) we can deform the integration contour $\Gamma$ into an integration contour $\Gamma^{\prime\prime}$ with the same endpoints that goes though the stationary point $z_0$ in the direction of steepest descent$^1$.
2. Since the $\Gamma^{\prime\prime}$ contour integral is exponentially suppressed in $\lambda$ away from the stationary point $z_0$, we can replace $\Gamma^{\prime\prime}$ with the tangent $\Gamma^{\prime}$ (or an appropriate double-sided line segment thereof) at $z_0$. The endpoints are to a large extent irrelevant.

--

$^1$ If the deformation crosses poles and/or branch cuts, their effect (such as, [residues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)) have to be taken into account. Also note that there can be more than one stationary point. Another effect is the [Stokes phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_phenomenon).

Comment: Thanks @QMechanic. Regarding point (1), let $a,b$ be the endpoints of $\Gamma$ and let $z_0$ be the stationary point. Then $\Gamma''$ has the same endpoints $a,b$ and passess through $z_0$ in the direction of steepest descent. My doubt is exactly why such a contour exists. If the region $\Omega$ is path connected, then we can always find $\Gamma''_{a,z_0}$ conecting $a$ to $z_0$ and $\Gamma''_{z_0,b}$ connecting $z_0$ to $b$. Therefore we can always find a path from $a$ to $b$ through $z_0$. But why we can always choose it so that it passess through $z_0$ *in the steepest descent direction*?

Comment: I updated the answer.